# The points A $(0,0)$, B$(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha))$ and C $(\cos(\beta),\sin(\beta))$ are the vertices of a right angled triangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, polar-coordinates

**[[image: The points A <span class=]$(0,0)$, B$(\cos(\alpha),\sin(\alpha))$ and C $(\cos(\beta),\sin(\beta))$ are the vertices of a right angled triangle. Derive a relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6cNc.jpg)**

I tried using the slope method, basically that $m_{1}\times m_{2}=-1$ and I got the relation that:

$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=0$

Clearly $\alpha-\beta=\pi/2$, i.e. $\sin(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$

But one case which I think should also be considered is $\alpha-\beta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$, which would result in a negative value for  $\cos(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2})$, but the answer to the referenced image doesn't consider it. Why? (The answer given is (A) and (C))

Comment: Because $\alpha <\pi/2$ and $\beta <\pi/2$, $\alpha -\beta \ne 3\pi/2$

Comment: @Vasili Why do you think the variables are less than $\pi/2$?

Comment: Please see the **edit-images** section of [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) for a discussion of the use of images in your MathSE postings.

Comment: It's not unusual for a textbook/workbook to have a few problems which are poorly asked or a few items in the answer key which are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four answers are correct.

Notice the problem says "if", not "if and only if", so an answer is correct if its inequality implies that the triangle is a right triangle.

You are correct that the triangle is a right triangle if and only if $\cos(\alpha-\beta) = 0$.

We have the double angle formulas

$$ \cos(\alpha-\beta) = 2 \cos^2 \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} - 1 $$
$$ \cos(\alpha-\beta) = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} $$

By the first,

$$ \cos \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies \cos(\alpha-\beta) = 0 $$

By the second,

$$ \sin \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \implies \cos(\alpha-\beta) = 0 $$

So each of the four conditions is sufficient to show that the triangle is a right triangle. Of course, only two of them can be true for a single scenario, so these are not necessary conditions.

Comment: I was trying to solve this by the graphical method. So what as it is clear that they are polar coordinates. So using some simple geometry I figured out the relation $\cos(\alpha-\beta)$=0 now depending on whether $\alpha>\beta$ or otherwise, I could get three relations out of the 4, but I couldn't get $\cos=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Here is the image for more reference. https://ibb.co/g9Pm6gC

Comment: $\alpha=\frac{7\pi}{4}, \beta=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks